# How can I cause consistency error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I've got following error in `dbcc checkdb` output from our customer for one table (more of very similar lines):

> Msg 8964, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Table error: Object ID 212503619, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594046251008, alloc unit ID
>   72057594048675840 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:705), slot 0, text ID 328867287793664 is not referenced.
>
> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 49 consistency errors in table 'X' (object ID 2126630619).

This error was created when running upgrade of our software (if he restores DB from backup and run the upgrade again, the same issue reappears).

My question is - how can I possibly create this kind of error from my app? I always thought that this kind of error must be caused by some environmental (HDD) problem, but I've seen the same issue on the same table on another environment. I tried the same steps as him, but without success.

Thanks!

Comment: If you run `dbcc checkdb` on the db before the upgrade, what happens?

Comment: @chuex, without any error. I've double-checked that.

Comment: Excuse me, are you trying to replicate the issue in your environment for debug purpose (to retrieve what's the cause) or would you like simply to solve?

Comment: @FrancescoDeLisi, I'm trying to reproduce for finding the possible cause. Removing the error for customer would be simple, it has only few rows and I can easily remove them and insert again.

Comment: Actually to repair it you should use `DBCC CheckDB(<Database Name>) WITH REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`. A possible cause: your DB backup has less rows then the actual (in few words, it's older) with consequent `INDEX` issues. Try to backup the last DB, upgrade your app and restore. I think it's a DB problem.

Comment: This [old article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-bug-that-people-are-hitting-msg-8967-level-16-state-216/) mentions obtaining further information from the error log; that might be a way to find out exactly what happened.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, this is probably a severe bug in SQL Server. It is not possible to cause corruption using documented and supported T-SQL. To cause corruption you need

1. hardware problems
2. OS-level file system problems (filter drivers, ...)
3. Undocumented commands like DBCC WRITEPAGE
4. A severe bug

Can you single-step through the upgrade script? If not, try tracing it with SQL Profiler. Find the statement that first makes corruption appear.

Here is a simpler, less noisy command:

```
DBCC CHECKDB([AdventureWorks2012]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```